# AlertDialog showing multiple Dialogs on top of each other?

Tags: android, dialog, gps, android-alertdialog

I have this method in my GPSTracker:

```
public void showSettingsAlert() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    // alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            myContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

When I am running it, I keep getting like 10 dialogs at once on top of each other, so basically I can then press 10times cancel or something like that, how do I fix it?
I read about

```
final AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
if(alert.isShowing()) {
alert.dismiss();
}
else {
alert.show();
}
```

But that didnt work for me, I am still getting multiple dialogs over each other... Can someone help me out please? Basically I am calling if(gps.isEnabled()) gps.showSettingsAlert(); on my Activity.

```
if (itemsArrayList.get(position).getCoordinates() == null || !gps.canGetLocation()) {
            holder.distance.setText("Distance not available");
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
```

Comment: Please post more of your code.  There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted so far, so the issue is elsewhere.  If you post more code, it will make it easier for someone to identify the issue.

Comment: post the code where your calling `showSettingsAlert`

Comment: I added the code where I call showSettingsAlert.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution provide by Phan Văn Linh is the key just need some little modification.

- First of all make an alertDialog as a globale variable of your activity or Application (depending on  you) and initialize it as null.

  private AlertDialog.Builder _alertDialog = null;

The null initialisation will help you to check if an instance of the alertDialog was create or not.

- Then make the showSettingDialgo like this:

  public void showSettingsAlert() {
  if( _alertDialog != null){//Here we check if an instance is displayed or not
     return;
  }

  _alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext);
  // Setting Dialog Title
  ...
  _alertDialog.show();
  }
- At last when the dialog is dismissed make the instance null again.

  _alertDialog = null;

Comment: I can't get it to work, it still shows me a lot of dialogs on top of others.
I have 
public class GpsTracker extends Service implements LocationListener { } in which my showSettingsAlert is inside and then got my ListAdapter, and there I need to show up the GPS...

Comment: Can you show more code about yopur GPSTracker and how you use it please ?

Answer (score -1):

Make `alertDialog` as a global variable of your Activity class
Then in`showSettingsAlert()`, you can check the alert is showing or not.

```
private AlertDialog alertDialog;
...
public void showSettingsAlert() {
    if( alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing() ){
       return;
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);    
    // Setting Dialog
    //builder.setTitle(...)
    //builder.setMessage...
    //builder.setPositiveButton...
    //builder.setNegativeButton...   
    ...
    alertDialog= builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: the isShowing() method is not available to AlertDialog.Builder :(

Comment: @HappyR you are right, my bad. I have update my answer. please check it